# Creating new Keras model by calling from an old (trained) one, new model summary is collapsed, how to unfold the new model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, summary

When we create a new Keras model using a trained one, the summary of the new one does not show each layer, how to unfold it or generate a new one with each layer explicitly exposed in summary?

```
Model: "m_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
m1_input (InputLayer)           [(None, 32, 32, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
m1_flat (Flatten)               (None, 3072)         0           m1_input[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
m1_dense1 (Dense)               (None, 5)            15365       m1_flat[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
m1_dense2 (Dense)               (None, 5)            30          m1_dense1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
m1_add (Add)                    (None, 5)            0           m1_dense1[0][0]                  
                                                                 m1_dense2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 10)           60          m1_add[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 15,455
Trainable params: 15,455
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "m_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
new_inp (InputLayer)         [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
m_1 (Model)                  (None, 10)                15455     
=================================================================
Total params: 15,455
Trainable params: 15,455
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The code issue reproduction is as below (it would be greatly appreciated if you can work on top of this snippet):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

m1_input = layers.Input(shape=(32,32,3),name='m1_input')
m1_flatten = layers.Flatten(name='m1_flat')(m1_input)
m1_dense1 = layers.Dense(5,name='m1_dense1')(m1_flatten)
m1_dense2 = layers.Dense(5,name='m1_dense2')(m1_dense1)
m1_add = layers.Add(name='m1_add')([m1_dense1,m1_dense2])
m1_dense3 = layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')(m1_add)
m1 = keras.Model(inputs=m1_input,outputs = m1_dense3,name='m_1')

m1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

inp = layers.Input(shape=(32,32,3),name='new_inp')
out = m1(inp)
m2 = keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out, name='m_2')

print(m1.summary())
print(m2.summary())
```

Please don't use `m2 = keras.Model(inputs=m1.input, outputs=m1.output)`, which does not serve the purpose of creating a new model by calling an old one in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with this line: `out = m1(inp)`
When I call `m2.get_layer(name='m1_flat', index=None) # also 'm1_dense1', 'm1_dense1', 'm1_add')` it returns `ValueError: No such layer: m1_flat`

Comment: `tensorflow.__version__`: `1.14.0-rc1`. The code has no issue running in this env.